# Starcraft 2: The Dig - How do I scan?

Tags: starcraft-2

http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Campaign/The_Dig

> Cheap Trick 3 When you're given
>   control of the Laser Drill you can use scan...

I don't have scan in my command center. How can I scan then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have advanced enough through the campaign to purchase the orbital command upgrade for the command center from the armory.

If you want to follow that particular trick, you'll need to complete more missions elsewhere to unlock the orbital command, and then return to the level with your enhanced gear.

I managed to get vision for the drill with cloaked wraiths (though there are a *ton* of photon cannons as well).